# Appium UI Automator Viewer

Tags: appium

I can capture one screen of an app(Whatsapp) on UI Automator.
System Shows:-
 Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file. Error while parsing UI hierarchy XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file

Answer (score 0):

you have to stop appium while it is running  and run only UI Automator Viewer

Comment: @Emma I have done that .....for rest of apps its working fine ..... but when i try to capture the screenshot of whatsapp screen... It showing me the above error message

Comment: why the down vote ? i have to solve similar problem like this way

Comment: There is probably an animation going on the screen you want to capture. UIAutomatorViewer does not like that :) If you using appium, then use your IDE to run in debug mode and then just get the page source and see the elements that way... it normally works

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the appium server as well as kill the cmd hosting it

Answer (score 0):

1. stop the appium server.
2. Make sure the port is also free from which device was connected to appium earlier.